# Using ajax to update content via mysql,

Tags: ajax, css-selectors, self-updating

```
function sendValues() {
    var str = $("#ryan_m").serialize();
var response = $('input[name=product[]]:checked').val();
$.ajax({
    url: "/post.php?avoidcache=' + myTimestamp();",
    data: {str}
    cache: false
});
```

}

I want to update my sql query on the fly in the form of a checkbox. this script works but I have to click the form 'submit' button to see the results, Is there a way I can update after I click/Unclick the checkboxes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assume your checkboxes has class attributes "valueSender", then you can add the following

`$(".valueSender").change(function(){
  sendValues();
});`

Comment: Am I going to be able to update this query without reloading the page, I've tried your suggesstion and It did not work

Comment: You should be able to. Can you please show your html as well and outline which checkbox that should trigger the ajax?

Comment: <tr>
 <td width='124' height='113'>$image</a><br />
  <form action="post.php?scode=$productid" method="get"/>
   <input type="checkbox" name="product[]" class="valueSender" value="$productid" id="$model"/>
    <label for="$model">Compare</label>
    <span id="results">Compare</span>

Comment: Sorry for this sloppiness, Basically, I have values relating to a search query such as brand, price, category, and I want to able to click the checkbox and have it only display those values

Comment: no worries. Have you tried to put the `$(".valueSender").change(function(){ sendValues(); });` inside `$(document).ready(function(){   });` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just bind to the change event and call the `sendValues()` function as soon as the event fires. With jQuery e.g.: `$('input[name=product[]]').change(function() { sendValues(); });`